# Notion of complex optima

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers

Consider the function:

$$y = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + x$$

Suppose we wanted to determine its local optima, but instead of looking at local optima with domain  $R$ we instead consider domain $C$ and range $C$. We thus continue the process as is intuitive:

$$y' = x^2 + 1$$
$$y'=0 \rightarrow x = \pm i $$

Now clearly the two stationary points for the second derivative are at the complex values of $\pm i$. The normal intuition of them being relatively less than their surroundings and relatively more than their surroundings doesn't appear to make immediate sense since complex numbers aren't directly comparable.

So I came up with the following hypothesis

Given

$$y = f(x)$$
All points in C where
$$y' = f'(x) = 0$$
Are local optima for
$$y = |f(x)|$$

Is this correct? How do I show it?

I would be perplexed if it weren't.

Comment: Better prepare to be perplexed, then. (I'll leave the explanation to others. Hint: Complex analytic functions are *open* maps.)

Comment: If you're going to go down this road you *have* to be more precise about specifying the domain and range spaces. For instance, in your first example, $\pm i$ are *not* stationary points unless the function is defined as $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant you have a valid point, but I have already made that specification in the second sentence. I suppose it would be easier to read if I just explicitly wrote $x \in C$ for future readers?

Comment: I think so, yes. Because then you seem make the leap to looking at the *range* of the function in the second half; i.e. $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen , how does the global property of openness help make statements about the relationship between stationary points and the local regions around them? (I'm a bit of a newb @ complex analysis, forgive the inexperience)

Comment: Openness is really a local property (with global consequences). For any $z$ in the domain of $f$, if you take any neighbourhood of $z$ then $f$ maps this neighbourhood onto a neighbourhood of $f(z)$. This immediately rules out any local maximum for $|f|$, and ditto for minima except in the trivial case $f(z)=0$.

Comment: Is that related to this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Comment: God this is really not what i was expecting. So complex "optima" are basically always saddle points?